# Cropping2D layer crops to wrong dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, keras, crop

I have an 1920-by-1153-by-3 keras tensor that needs to be cropped to 1920-by-1080. However, creating a Cropping layer and passing the difference of the shapes gives it the wrong dimensions. This method gives the tensor the shape of 1920-by-1920.

Code:

```
        def crop(x, size):
            shape = K.int_shape(x)
            shape_diff = shape[1] - size[1], shape[2] - size[2]
            print(shape_diff)
            y = tf.keras.layers.Cropping2D(shape_diff)(x)
            return y
```

Partial output of model.summary and shape_diff:

Shape_diff:
`(0,72)`

model.summary:

```
conv2d_transpose_4 (Conv2DTr (None, 1920, 1152, 3)     195       
_________________________________________________________________
cropping2d (Cropping2D)      (None, 1920, 1008, 3)     0         
=================================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by dividing the sides by 2, since the Keras docs state:

> If tuple of 2 ints: interpreted as **two different symmetric** cropping values for height and width.